# Post Custom Message in the channel when the new app(tab) is added in channel

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there any way we can send a custom message to the channel when the new tab/app is added to the teams? I need to change the default message shown in the picture below when we add the app to the teams.

[image: microsoft-teams image description]

Comment: Hi AM4K, it is by design, so we can't add custom messages when new tab is added.

Answer (score 0):

it is by design, so we can't add custom messages when new tab is added.